# How to create a page tabs without iframes now in Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

is it possible to create a page tab without iframes in Facebook now? -how to add a tabs using FBML?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has already deprecated page tabs using FBML, iframe is the only method now.  This is mentioned on their [developer roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/):

> We will stop allowing new FBML apps,
>   but will continue to support existing
>   FBML tabs and apps. Instead, we
>   recommend using iframes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.., Any idea How we can publish a tab directly from our site?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as long as your application is sandboxed.

In your application setting on Facebook:

[image: Sandbox mode]

[image: Deprecated FBML]

If you enable "Sandbox Mode", the lower config will be available. However, this is not the way you should be building apps today. Iframes and web standards are the way to go.

Now, my question is, why do you want to do this?